# How i can include external module from cx freeze python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using install some external modules using pip but at the time I tried to create an executable from pyinstaller as well as CZ freeze it's my executable is not working

```
enter code here

import os

from plyer import notification # <- I want to include plyer in the notification at the time of installation 

import os


class WindowsPopUp:

def __init__(self):
    print("start")


def popup(self,question,ans):
     notification.notify(
         title="question",
         message="ans",
         app_name='Here is the application name')

#main work is begings create tooltip 
notification.notify(
title="sdsd",
message="dsd",
app_name='Here is the application name')


os.system("pause")
```

`

its show error my `.exe` shows error

Comment: Hi, please share more details. I am unable to understand your problem.

Comment: Is the `player` a custom module?

Comment: i am just plyer is library for toolbar notifcation i get this module by pip install plyer and also wanted to know can i use py2exe or pinstaller even show error my executable